# How to get content of table cell with selected radio?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, radio-button, cell

I'm trying to get the content of the cell with the selected radio.
This is my JavaScript, but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById(document.querySelector('input[name="celselectie"]:checked').parentNode).innerHTML=(here some var);
```

HTML:

```
<table id="speelveld">
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel001"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel002"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel003"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel004"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel005"/></td>
[.......]
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel099"/></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="celselectie" value="cel100 "/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You don't have any input named "selection", you are using `celselectie`.

Comment: oops. I was about to change the name of the radio buttons to "selection" but forgot :l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`document.querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), *returns the first element within the document that matches the specified group of selectors*.

*So your code will not work as for catching multiple elements.*

**Here is my approach:**

1) get all the radio button with name `celselectie`

```
var d = document.getElementsByName('celselectie');
```

2) Iterate it and check  it *"checked"* property, if it is `true` then get its **`parentNode`** and print the `innerText`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    if (d[i].checked) {          
        console.log(d[i].parentNode.innerText);
    }
}
```

---

**Final Code:**

```
var d = document.getElementsByName('celselectie');    
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    if (d[i].checked) {          
        console.log(d[i].parentNode.innerText);
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/5qbWU/)